# Visualizing a twisted solid

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d

"A square of side length $s$ lies in a plane perpendicular to a line $L$. One vertex
of the square lies on $L$. As this square moves a distance $h$ along $L$, the square turns one revolution about
$L$ to generate a corkscrew-like column with square cross-sections. Find the volume of the column."

Now, solving the problem was easy enough(Cross-section is always $s^2$ so volume is $h s^2$)

The problem lies in me being unable to understand the 3d figure of the column. How does the diagram look?

Comment: If $A$ is the vertex that remains on the axis, each of the 3 vertices $B,C,D$ describe an helix with equations : $(t, c \cos(t),c \sin(t))$,  $(t, \sqrt{2}c \cos(t-\pi/4),\sqrt{2}c \sin(t-\pi/4))$, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple... it looks like this..........:

[image]

In the continuous case:

### [image]

In case anyone wants the *Mathematica* code:

```
myCube = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, .1}];
Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.02], Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2 \[Pi]}}],
  Table[{Opacity[0.3], Hue[RandomReal[]],
    GeometricTransformation[
     GeometricTransformation[myCube, 
      TranslationTransform[{0, 0, \[Theta]}]], 
     RotationTransform[\[Theta], {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}]]}, 
    {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], .1}]}]
```

Comment: Umm... For the person who voted to delete this correct answer:  Please explain why.